# Self leveling floor concrete vs concrete board

Tags: hardwood-floor

I have glue down solid oak hardwood floors throughout my whole house. In my guest bathroom there is a water leak somewhere that is affecting the wood floors that room and in the adjacent rooms. While I am waiting on my plumber, I decided to start getting bids on replacing the wood in this bathroom with tile. Because the wood floors are 3/4” thick and the tile is a 1/4” thick, the bathroom floor will need to be build up for an even flow from one room to another. One contractor recommended using self leveling concrete compound. I’m concerned that the water used in this compound will cause even more damage to the hardwood in the adjacent rooms. Am I correct to be worried about this? What will work best in this room to build the floor up without damaging the adjacent hardwood floors?

Comment: "Am I correct to be worried about this? "    Don't worry.  The leveling compound dries very quickly.  It works by a catalytic action, not evaporation.

Comment: The subfloor needs to be built up _for stability_ more than for  a level alignment. You likely have 3/4" material under the hardwood, which isn't adequate for tile.

Comment: I wouldn't worry right now about the 1/2" difference.  You're going to need a substrate for the tile anyway—assuming both flooring types share the same subfloor.  By the time you get your substrate down (whether it's Ditra or 1/4" cement board, plus your thinset, you're probably just about right there.

Comment: Concentrate on fixing the leak. If you can't shut off the water to that bathroom without shutting off the rest of the house, get that sorted when you have the leak fixed. Shutoff valves are **A Good Thing.** Or *"completely unnecessary; until you need them."*

Comment: 1/8" of thinset under the backer board, 1/2" of backer board, 1/8" of thinset under the tile, and 1/4" tile, equals one inch. Now you're 1/4" higher than the rest, which is how it always works out if you *do it right*. "Because the wood floors are 3/4” thick" ... and **1/4" tile, installed, is 1” thick**... it should all work out fine.

Answer (score 6):

I would not use self-leveling compound in general unless there's a real need for it (out-of-level, significant unevenness). It's not a great solution as it's soft and chalky and likely to disintegrate over time unless on a very rigid substrate. It tends to be suggested by those looking to shave time, not provide the best solution.

I would install cement board or plywood, properly fastened.

That said, self-leveling compound isn't the liquid slurry folks tend to imagine. It's rather thick, like honey, when mixed properly. If you see it sloshing around it was overwatered and will not have a good outcome. So, the moisture isn't really a problem, but it should be kept from direct contact with your finished floor by a buffer strip or other means.

Comment: Plywood? I guess, but if you are putting tile on it, I really think that backerboard is a better choice. It has similar expansion constants to tile, so it doesn't has less cracking from thermal cycles.

Comment: I can't argue with that. It's a matter of availability, budget, etc. Many a tile floor has been built on half-inch CDX over 3/4" OSB.